# getDatabaseConnectionByName returns PASS_VALUE instead of actual db password from environment

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I am working on a project where we have multiple environments and for each environment we have a separate database connection string which I have added in environments section.

Now I want to get the environment connection string at runtime using Groovy test step to use it further to execute query. Below is my script:

```
def connectionString = context.testCase.testSuite.project.activeEnvironment.databaseConnectionContainer.getDatabaseConnectionByName("dbconnection").getConnectionString()
```

Now in response I am getting connection error as I can see in response the script is returning `jdbc:oracle:thin:Username/PASS_VALUE@machine details`. As per my understanding the `PASS_VALUE` is causing this issue.

```
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" )
import groovy.sql.Sql;
//get active environment connection string
def connectionString = context.testCase.testSuite.pro
log.info ("Connection String#####"+connectionString)
def driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
def  con = Sql.newInstance(connectionString,driver);
```

So this `getConnectionString()` should return the password so that it can be used in further script.